# Hidden directory .quarantine appearing in WordPress root directory upon install

Tags: wordpress, virus

I run a development script that launches WordPress sites from the command line. I noticed that a hidden directory ".quarantine" appears in my root WordPress install for about 10 seconds after the script, then it vanishes.

Automattic does all kinds of shady stuff when you launch, and when you launch certain plugins. [i.e. WooCommerce changes file permissions - without user permission or notification! - And does what? Ask your local Government.] Anyway...

Yes, there are a bunch of wordpress.org plugins. No absolutely nothing I'm doing could cause .quarantine to appear on my site. These are cloud installs running from bare metal OSs. It's not me.

The question is:
Have I been hacked? Or is this part of some known process associated with WordPress core or somehow allowed to happen by a repo plugin [I'm thinking it's Woo]. Anybody know anything?